# chart js put meter square / superscript on y axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, charts, chart.js

I would like to put meter square (m<sup>2</sup>) in chart js y axis.

I have the following function :

```
var floorOptions = {
animation: true,
scaleLabel: 
function(label){return label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + ' m<sup>2</sup>';}
```

};

it doesn't work. Can someone please assist? Thx

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var floorOptions = {
    animation: true,
    scaleLabel: 
    function(label){return label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + ' m/\u00B2'
;}
```

Canvas doesn't support HTML tags, but you could use the unicode character for superscript '2'.

[link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)